# Does Kubernetes support ejabberd?

Tags: kubernetes, ejabberd

I can run ejabberd service on docker swarm. 
Do I Deployment a ejabberd service on kubernetes ?

YML for swarm:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  ejabberd:
    image: ejabberd/ecs:18.03
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 5222:5222
      - 5269:5269
      - 5280:5280
    volumes:
      - ./ejabberd/database/:/home/ejabberd/database/
      - ./ejabberd/logs/:/home/ejabberd/logs/
      - ./ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml:/home/ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml
networks:
  backend:
    external: true
```

Comment: I was able to find some work in progress helm charts from a quick google but not an official one. Possible nobody has yet created a stable set of deployment descriptors for kubernetes but you could maybe pick up one of the work in progress ones or there might be more out there I'm missing.

Comment: Maybe worth giving https://github.com/ecliptic/helm-charts/tree/master/ejabberd a try

Answer (score 6):

This is a basic deployment yaml file for kubernetes without volumes. you can add some volume mounts also depending how are you using them.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ejabberd-deployment
  labels:
    app: ejabberd
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ejabberd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ejabberd
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ejabberd
        image: ejabberd/ecs
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5280
        - containerPort: 5222
        - containerPort: 5269
```